# Alignment of Google Maps Overlay

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, heatmap

I have over layed a heat map of housing prices over google maps. For the data in the heat map, I have latitude, longitude, and home prices. I used the max and min latitudes and longitudes to set the NW and SE bounds found in the google maps api. But when I overlay the .png image, the heat map does not align with the correct latitudes and longitude. Do I need to convert into pixels or do a Mercantor Projection. I am trying to overlay the heat map onto a certain zip code but the heat map is not aligning correctly with google maps. Any Ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>           
<head>       
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        html, body, #map-canvas {
             height: 100%;
             margin: 0px;
             padding: 0px
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
    <script>


var overlay;

testOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.25,-76.5),
 };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP);
    var swBound = new google.maps.LatLng(39.238914, -77.529792);
    var neBound = new google.maps.LatLng(40.2843987, -76.451227);
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(swBound, neBound);

    var srcImage = 'ratio.png';

    overlay = new testOverlay(bounds, srcImage, map);

 }

 function testOverlay(bounds, image, map){

    this.bounds_ = bounds;
    this.image_ = image;
    this.map_ = map;
    this.div_ = null;
    this.setMap(map);
    }

 testOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {

      var div = document.createElement('div');
      div.style.borderStyle = 'none';
      div.style.borderWidth = '0px';
      div.style.position = 'absolute';
      var img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = this.image_;
      img.style.width = '100%';
      img.style.height = '100%';
      img.style.opacity = '0.75';
      img.style.position = 'absolute';
      div.appendChild(img);
      this.div_ = div;
      var panes = this.getPanes();
      panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
  };

 testOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {
      var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();
      var sw =        overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getSouthWest());
      var ne =  overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getNorthEast());
      var div = this.div_;
      div.style.left = sw.x + 'px';
      div.style.top = ne.y + 'px';
      div.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + 'px';
      div.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + 'px';
    };

 testOverlay.prototype.updateBounds = function(bounds){
            this.bounds_ = bounds;
                    this.draw();
                        };

 testOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function() {
    this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
    this.div_ = null;
 };



  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

   </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
![Heat Map of Prices graphed against latitude and lonitude][1]</html>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmXCM.png

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/d7akkmz5/)

Comment: Where is it supposed to be?

Comment: it is supposed to be an overlay of zip code 21222. The heat map is supposed to be an overlay of the whole zip code and it doesnt cover all the addresses that are present in the plot

Comment: The bounds of zip code 21222 are: east: -76.443482,
west: -76.540847, south: 39.214707, north: 39.293047; looks to me like your data doesn't match that area.

Comment: You also have information on your heatmap image that belongs outside of the geographic area (the legend and x/y axis labels).

Comment: [When I crop the image to remove all the extraneous stuff outside the geographic data, and use the bounds for 21222 rather than those you provided, it looks better, the bounds are still slightly off](http://jsfiddle.net/d7akkmz5/1/)

Comment: when I use the same code that you use, my image still does not cover the whole zip code.